# processing multiple files in business objects data services

Tags: business-objects

I am new to the Business Objects Data services.

I have to run a dataflow reading from a file. Filename should be read based on wild chars like *Platform*. And I want to run the dataflow only if the file exists, if file is not present , it should not error out or should not do anything but it should just move on to the next dataflow or workflow in the job.

I tried below code to check if the file exists as built_in function File_Exists cannot check the file based on wild chars.

*$FILEEXISTSFLAG= exec('/bin/ksh',' "ls xxxxxx/*Platform*.csv',8);*

My intention is based on the value assigned to $FILEEXISTSFLAG from above code, I will decide whether to execute the data flow or not (if $FILEEXISTSFLAG is null do nothing otherwise execute the data flow ) but its retrieving below output.

*ls: cannot access /xxxxxx/*Platform*.csv: No such file*

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the above problem by using the index function.

$FILEEXISTSFLAG is containing a value like "ls: cannot access *Platform*: No such file or directory ". So, I have used the index function as below. So if the output is not null for below index function, it will execute the dataflow, otherwise it will do nothing.

index( $FILEEXISTSFLAG , 'No such file',1)

Thanks, 
Phani.